# Unable to run scripts for installing UTL_SMTP

Tags: oracle10g

My oracle version is

---

Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Prod
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.3.0  Production
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production

I am logging into the **sysdba** with username **sys**
when I am trying to run the following scripts I am getting this error

SQL> @$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlmail.sql

Error reading file

SQL> @$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/prvtmail.plb

Error reading file

What configuration do I have to do? Can I anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

SQL*Plus doesn't recognise Unix `$` environment variables, at least when you're on a Windows platform. You can give the full path to the files - i.e. expand the variable - or there is a built-in shorthand you can use:

```
SQL> @?/rdbms/admin/utlmail.sql
```

In this context, `?` represents your `ORACLE_HOME`; it isn't a bind variable, for example.

But before you run anything... as far as I'm aware `UTL_SMTP` is installed by default; while logged in as `SYS`, does `desc utl_smtp` say it doesn't exist? Or is it just not available to other users, which would be a privilege issue?

Comment: well thanks.. Its already installed in this version. I checked it last night.. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @alpha_calling - no problem; so if you were looking because a normal user tried to call something in the package and it said it didn't exist, you need to `grant execute on utl_smtp to user`. Or to a role, but if it's going to be used in a package then it needs to be a direct grant to the user anyway...